# Is golden ratio the most aesthetically pleasing ratio?

Tags: mathematics, art

I have read several claims in all kinds of literature (both scientific, less scientific and downwards anti-scientific) about golden ratio and its "aesthetics".

However, all the "proofs" I have seen seemed to me like arbitrarily chosen and ignored all kind of aesthetically pleasing ratios, like 1:2, 2:3 etc., that appear in various art, too.

So, my question is - was the claim that "golden ratio is the most aesthetically pleasing ratio" ever really proved?

(note: I have seen other claims about golden ratio, that seemed unfounded, but I will leave that for later. Right now I want to focus on the claim of aesthetics.)

Comment: My own half-answer: I have found this website now - http://goldenratiomyth.weebly.com/phi-in-psychology.html

Comment: You're asking if an opinion has ever been proved?

Comment: Yes, because the claims usually talk about something that is *universally* more pleasing and *universally* aesthetical. Also, the question was marked as a duplicate for completely different question. Well... all right, I guess?

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a notable claim. In my art studies, I've often seen the claim that the golden ratio is aesthetically _significant_ in art composition, but I haven't run across the claim that it's _superior_ to the exclusion of everything else. On the contrary, most serious art instruction (in my experience) favors simpler guidelines like the rule of thirds, and most photographic tools default to the rule of thirds rather than 1:φ. The idea that the golden ratio is “ideal” is more a matter of trivia – can you point to notable examples?